# Submitting form refreshing the page even after using e.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do some operations after submitting of form. But the page gets reloaded after clicking of "Submit" button. I have used evt.preventDefault() still its not stopped.

```
    <form class="user-info-form">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="create-user-label">User Details</h4>
                    <div class="error-message"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-email" class="control-label">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user-email" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-first-name" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-first-name" name="first_name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-last-name" class="control-label">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-last-name" name="last_name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-confirm-password" class="control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirm-password" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="uuid" />

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And JS code is -

```
$(".submit-btn").submit(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            oThis.onSubmitBtn();
        });
```

Comment: First: You want to submit the form, not the button, so you need to go for: $(".user-info-form").submit(....), then your prevent should work. Second: In your code it is not clear what oThis is. If the form still submits, it's often a javascript error.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the `submit` function to your `form` tag, not to your submit button.

```
$(".user-info-form").submit(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        oThis.onSubmitBtn();
    });
```